# Combinar cifras de dos números en un punto

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenas, quiero combinar las cifras de dos números en un punto exacto de manera que una parte del número 1 esté en el 2 y viceversa. Un ejemplo sería: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tenemos 6 números con un valor cada uno de manera que queremos obtener los dos con mayor valor. Luego reproducir dos veces cada número para llegar a 6 números de nuevo y variar cada número de esos 4 haciendo la recombinación como en la foto mostrada abajo

El método realiza bien tanto la obtención de los dos números con valor máximo como la reproducción pero no la recombinación como se ve en el resultado mostrado por pantalla.

El problema es que no obtenemos el resultado que queremos con el código creado.

```
for i in range(len(poblacionNueva)-indAReproducir):
    punto = random.randint(1,largo-1) #Se elige un punto para hacer el intercambio
    padre = random.sample(selected, 2) #Se eligen dos padres
    poblacionNueva[i][:punto] = padre[0][:punto] #Se mezcla el material genetico de los padres en cada nuevo individuo 
    poblacionNueva[i][punto:] = padre[1][punto:] #(: significa trocear la cadena)

    poblacionDef = [x[1] for x in poblacionNueva]
```

El resultado que obtenemos es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Editar 1:
Resultado con la respuesta de Patricio Moracho:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Editar 2:

Muestra de variables:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Edit 3: No realiza el split bien

```
Punto: 4
Padre: [[3, [5, 0, 3, 7, 3]], [2, [9, 6, 7, 7, 9]]]
Padre[0]: [3, [5, 0, 3, 7, 3]]
Padre[1]: [2, [9, 6, 7, 7, 9]]
PoblacionNueva[i][:punto]: [3, [5, 0, 3, 7, 3]]
PoblacionNueva[i][punto:]: []
PoblacionDef: [[5, 0, 3, 7, 3], [8, 9, 9, 8, 9], [7, 1, 8, 1, 1], [9, 1, 8, 0, 6], [9, 6, 7, 7, 9], [5, 0, 3, 7, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carlos, por un lado mencionas la combinación de dos número y por el otro muestras un código dónde aparecen estructuras que parecieran ser una lista de listas. De cualquier forma, la mecánica es parecida y usa la técnica de "slice" que opera básicamente sobre datos tipo listas o cadenas. Veamos unos ejemplos:

Si quieres combinar dos números enteros, una forma es convertirlos en una cadena y hacer un slice:

```
n1 = 26641
n2 = 49356

print(str(n1)[0:3]+str(n2)[-2:])
26656
```

Ahora si lo que tenemos son listas, el procedimiento es idéntico

```
l1 = list(str(n1))
l2 = list(str(n2))

print(l1[0:3]+l2[-2:])
['2', '6', '6', '5', '6']
```

En tu código, el problema entiendo que es este:

```
poblacionNueva[i][:punto] = padre[0][:punto]
poblacionNueva[i][punto:] = padre[1][punto:]
```

Por un lado como comentaste, `padre` es una lista de listas con está estructura `[a, [b, c, d, e, f]]` y la combinación la quieres hacer sobre la lista interna, por lo que estás accediendo mal `padre[0]` accedes a `a` y con `padre[1]` accedes a `[b, c, d, e, f]` la lista que te interesa. Por las dudas, también lo comento: los límites en Python no son inclusivos, lo mismo ocurre por ejemplo con `range(3)` que devuelve `0,1,2`. Para lo que has enunciado, debiera ser:

```
poblacionNueva[0][:punto] = (padre[0])[1][:punto]
poblacionNueva[0][punto:] = (padre[1])[1][punto:]
```

Como demostración en función a tu ejemplo:

```
poblacionNueva = [
                  [0,0,0,0,0]
                ] 

padre = [[3, [9,0,5,3,9]], [2, [9,1,4,3,1]]]

punto = 2

poblacionNueva[0][:punto] = (padre[0])[1][:punto]
poblacionNueva[0][punto:] = (padre[1])[1][punto:]

print("Padre          : {0}".format(padre))
print("Punto          : {0}".format(punto))
print("poblacionNueva : {0}".format(poblacionNueva))

Padre          : [[3, [9, 0, 5, 3, 9]], [2, [9, 1, 4, 3, 1]]]
Punto          : 2
poblacionNueva : [[9, 0, 4, 3, 1]]
```

Como puedes ver, con el `punto = 2` obtienes una nueva lista con los dos primeros elementos de `padre[0])[1]` y los siguientes de `padre[1])[1]`

Comment: He cambiado la linea que has puesto y sigue sin funcionar. No me realiza la combinación de los puntos. Te dejo arriba editado la solución que me ha salido @Patricio Moracho

Comment: @CarlosLozano, revisa mi ejemplo final que coincide con tu ejemplo, por otro lado el punto de "slice" lo calculas con una función random, como te dás cuentas entonces que el valor no es el esperado si no tienes registro del punto de corte? Te sugiero: imprime en el ciclo las variables `punto, padre y poblacionNueva`, selecciona cualquier caso y agregalo a tu pregunta para revisarlo.

Comment: Claro, tenemos unas listas de tipo [a, [b,c,d,e,f]]. El valor inicial es una lista de 6 listas del tipo anterior que estan ordenadas de menor a mayor por el valor "a". Lo que queremos hacer es conservar las dos listas con mayor "a" , reproducir dos veces cada lista y realizar la combinación de las 4 primeras listas(numeros) .                                                                Si quieres te paso el método entero por si el fallo viene de otra parte aunque no creo porque conservar las dos listas y reproducirlas lo hace de manera correcta creemos.

Comment: Te sugiero: imprime en el ciclo las variables `punto, padre y poblacionNueva`, selecciona cualquier caso y agregalo a tu pregunta para revisarlo. Saludos.

Comment: Ya está editado

Comment: @CarlosLozano, ahi creo que encontré tu problema

Comment: Te actualizo en el edit el fallo porque hemos encontrado que no hace el split bien y te enseño lo que devuelve.

Comment: Carlos, no veo la forma que te devuelva ese valor con `punto = 4` si podría ser si `punto = 5`. Revisa [esta demostración](https://repl.it/Jvtq/1)

Comment: `punto`puede ser cualquier valor entre 1 y 4 ya que es el punto de corte del numero que tiene 5 cifras

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63282/discussion-between-patricio-moracho-and-carlos-lozano).

Comment: Vale, lo acabo de arreglar. Me faltaba el [1] en ambas lineas de poblacionNueva. `poblacionNueva[0][:punto] = (padre[0])[1][:punto]`
`poblacionNueva[0][punto:] = (padre[1])[1][punto:]`. ¿Me puedes explicar por qué pones eso?

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro.